# How can I add items to existing array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this one:

```
var data1 = [{ value: 'Afghan afghani', lubID: 'AFN' },{ value: 'Albanian lek', lubID: 'ALL' }];
```

What i want to do is to dynamically add items to data1 after it has been created. How can i do that?

Thank you.

Comment: @GergoErdosi OP is asking about putting values into that array.

Comment: creating array requires input values...where do those come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you push to any other array:

```
data1.push( { value: 'Something', lubID: 'Something Else'} );
```

If you're starting from an empty array, just define it first:

```
var data1 = [];
```

then start adding values using the push method I've shown you above.